# Have to return the key while I have specific value in the hash

Tags: ruby

I have a hash like the one shown below

```
profile={"acakxqcnwbhtfcppyilk"=>"unlocked", "achurktnaavqqnwtfvvt"=>"locked", "chrofmjydwzcbswhpste"=>"locked", "ChromeProfile"=>"unlocked", "clcqozsfdblntkwlcheo"=>"unlocked", "gpqhioztlmkoitjqxerm"=>"unlocked", "hododpaxflyzgpwortjl"=>"unlocked", "hyqnjrpttwclueqwttdw"=>"unlocked", "jtdeyzcxdpgblxmpldtx"=>"unlocked", "kifxvxmbifkicmapedir"=>"unlocked", "lucjkeeqzynhjurnpewl"=>"unlocked", "lyccchkgyscmljcvkvcj"=>"unlocked", "nmqhlowcqnwmwbxijwry"=>"unlocked", "nseucpicwbcyviargwjt"=>"unlocked", "osecuzrbvodwgkdwovjd"=>"unlocked", "pqhlxugxqppfybxdkemr"=>"unlocked", "qgoaryzyriohpwzbprgg"=>"unlocked", "rwtlttvtbrmziyuimgad"=>"unlocked", "sxkcvnlsgqauwcbkmjcy"=>"unlocked", "uyfvlzyllwimhklmmmns"=>"unlocked", "vgvobxhpflhappnajizs"=>"unlocked", "vlbbphwoyweyguhcmdwv"=>"unlocked", "vrsjncafxunswclescvu"=>"unlocked", "wxsninefjvtrxvntgkni"=>"unlocked", "xdqndtyyxctkovyfsldi"=>"unlocked", "ycvguesevlbopicmxfbc"=>"unlocked"}
```

I have to return the key which has the value 'locked', If there are more than one 'locked' is present, then the first one has to be returned.

Is there any specific method is available to accomplish task?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the `key()` method

```
profile.key('locked')
```

Read more [here](https://apidock.com/ruby/v2_5_5/Hash/key)

Comment: Perfect, that's what I want. Thanks.